# Getting details of why a file won't save after changes to a table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a macro-enabled Excel-file which fails to save with the error message

> Errors were detected while saving '[filepath]'. Microsoft Excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features. To make the repairs in a new file, click Continue. To Cancel saving the file, click Cancel.

After some trial and error it appears that the failure to save occurs when I choose "no fill colour" (under Home > Font) for a table in which someone has added colours in addition to the one in the table style.

Is there any way to see what error Excel encounters in some more detail than what is shown in the error message?

Is there some workaround to get the file saved anyway? Trying to click "Continue" and saving under another name does not work, I simply get another error message saying the file failed to save or some such.

There are no formula in the table, just numbers, although other sheets in the workbook draws data from it.

[image]

**-edit-** Of course, right after posting this question, I discovered "Home > Editing > Clear Formats" let me remove the colors and still allowed saving the workbook. Had to reapply the table style though. However, I am still very much interested in knowing what kind of error may have occurred.